# .NET KeyDown event to handle KeyChars

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-events, keycode

I made a form representing a numeric keypad, for a touchscreen application, and it contains the keys `0123456789`, along with the comma `,` key. Each key is an instance of a custom control with a property called Key which I set at design time:

```
   <Browsable(True),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Private _key As Char
    Property Key As Char
        Get
            Return _key
        End Get
        Set(value As Char)
            _key = value
            Me.Text = _key
        End Set
    End Property
```

To easily find the pressed key, in the containing form I build a `HashSet` with all the keys:

```
Private keys As HashSet(Of Char)
....
For Each c As Control In ...
   keys.Add(...)
Next
```

Then I listen for the `KeyDown` event:

```
AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf KeyHasBeenPressed
```

Then in the handler:

```
Private Sub KeyHasBeenPressed(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If keys.Contains(ChrW(e.KeyValue)) Then
        ' handle the key pressed event...
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is with the comma `,` key. The `Key` property has been set to `,` in the designer but at runtime the test `keys.Contains` fails because `e.KeyValue=188` and `e.KeyCode=Oemcomma {188}`.

What would be the best way to handle this situation? I want to use "special" keys like the comma and maybe the backspace key.

Also consider i8n: my physical numeric keypad shows a dot `.` but when pressed it must always be treated as a comma `,` instead.

Comment: why do you have the `If` statement? I can't immediately when this could return false.

Comment: @paul I want to handle only the keys which are in my form, it's a subset of all the available keys.

Comment: but surely you only call `AddHandler` for the keys on your form?

Comment: No, the handler doesn't handle the `KeyDown` event for each single key/button pressed, it handles the `KeyDown` event for the **containing control** (which is a panel in this case). Think about it: the user presses keys at the form level, otherwise he should set the focus on each key before "pressing" it. I'm not talking about the Click event, which is specific for each key, but about the user typing on a physical keyboard.

Comment: so your app is designed to accept input from either a touchscreen or via the keyboard, but only to acknowledge keyboard keystrokes if there is a corresponding form control?

Comment: @paul Exactly! Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `KeyPress` rather than `KeyDown` then you will be able to use the `KeyChar` property of `KeyPressEventArgs` which should return a ','

Comment: it works, but: 1) it won't handle special keys like the backspace and 2) it doesn't solve the `.` to be converted into `,` in the numeric keypad.